# How to write this HTML/PHP code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code and I am trying to write it in JavaScript so that a `document.getElementById().innerHTML` can be set to that code to then be displayed in html.
I can't for the life of me write this code in JavaScript, can anyone here?

```
<form action='create_new_invoice.php?name="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"' method="post" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">
<input type="hidden" name="Date" value="<?php echo $row["Date"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="StartTime" value="<?php echo $row["StartTime"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="FinishTime" value="<?php echo $row["FinishTime"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="Forename" value="<?php echo $row['Forename']; ?>"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="Surname" value="<?php echo $row['Surname']; ?>"></input>
<input type="submit" class='NewInvoice hidden-xs' style="border: 0; padding: 0;" value="New Invoice"></input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a good idea to separate your HTML from your Javascript code. PHP runs on the server, it gets rendered into text/html and sent to the browser where it gets parsed into an object. By separating your code, you can reuse things without having to rewrite everything. First define the HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="#" method="post" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">
    <input type="hidden" name="Date" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="StartTime" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="FinishTime" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Forename" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Surname" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class='NewInvoice hidden-xs' style="border: 0; padding: 0;" value="New Invoice" />
</form>
```

Then at the bottom, or using a window.onload even handler, have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myform = document.getElementById( 'myform' ); 
myform.setAttribute( "action", "/create_new_invoice.php?name=[VALUE]" ); 
myform["Date"].value = "[VALUE]";
myform["StartTime"].value = "[VALUE]";
myform["FinishTime"].value = "[VALUE]";
myform["Email"].value = "[VALUE]";
myform["Forename"].value = "[VALUE]";
myform["Surname"].value = "[VALUE]";
</script>
```

That will fill out the form, and can be turned into a function where you can reuse it to update the values of your form later if needed without messing with the HTML.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know you could do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string in javascript:

```
var htmlForm = '<form action="create_new_invoice.php?name='+  javascriptObject['Email']; +'" method="post" style="border: 0; padding: 0;">\
                <input type="hidden" name="Date" value="'+  javascriptObject["Date"]; +'" />\
                <input type="hidden" name="StartTime" value="'+  javascriptObject["StartTime"]; +'" />\
                <input type="hidden" name="FinishTime" value="'+  javascriptObject["FinishTime"]; +'" />\
                <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="'+  javascriptObject['Email']; +'"></input>\
                <input type="hidden" name="Forename" value="'+  javascriptObject['Forename']; +'"></input>\
                <input type="hidden" name="Surname" value="'+  javascriptObject['Surname']; +'"></input>\
                <input type="submit" class="NewInvoice hidden-xs" style="border: 0; padding: 0;" value="New Invoice"></input>';
```

And then add to some element ussing `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML(htmlForm);
```

The dynamic data you can store in a javascript object:

```
var javascriptObject = {
  "Email" : null,
  "Date" : null,
  "StartTime" : null,
  "FinishTime" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Forename" : null,
  "Surname" : null
};
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Took a bit of tinkering but it works